# Can't import obj in Python on OS X 10.6.3 Snow Leopard - libiconv.2.dylib?

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard, pyobjc

on OS X 10.6.3 Snow Leopard

```
% python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import objc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pyobjc_core-2.2-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/objc/__init__.py", line 22, in 
    _update()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pyobjc_core-2.2-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/objc/__init__.py", line 19, in _update
    import _objc
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pyobjc_core-2.2-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/objc/_objc.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pyobjc_core-2.2-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/objc/_objc.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _objc.so requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0
>>>
```

--
what do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'd try to temporary move `/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pyobjc_core-2.2-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/` to somewhere else and try the import statement again. This will enable the OS to import the version of `objc` that came with the OS by default (this is in `/System/Library`). By using the version in `/System/Library`, it works for me:

```
>>> import objc
>>> print objc.__file__ 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/objc/__init__.pyc
```

You might also consider moving `/opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib` to somewhere else. It looks outdated and OS X Snow Leopard has its own copy of `libiconv.2.dylib` in `/usr/lib` IIRC.

Comment: The libiconv appears to be installed from MacPorts.  You should either remove it or update it using the MacPorts port command.

Answer (score -3):

You more than likely screwed with the OS's Python installation, so you'll more than likely need to reinstall your OS.

Comment: It's not *that* drastic a problem!